# Not able to access extra arguments inside createAsyncThunk when passed through dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am passing an axios instance as extra argument to update user thunk action, but I am not able to access `extra` argument. I am only able to access all other fields like `getState`, `dispatch`, etc.
where axios instance is response from custom axios hook which i have used for adding token to headers before making request.

profile.jsx

```js
dispatch(updateUser(userData, { extra: { axios: axiosInstance } }));
```

userSlice.jsx

```js
const updateUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/update',
  async (userData, { dispatch, getState, extra }) => {
    try {
      const axiosInstance = extra.axios; 
      const response = await axiosInstance.put("/update-endpoint", userData);

      const responseData = response.data;

      return responseData;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: You can't access `extra` argument because it's given to the thunk middleware on setup.Just import  the axios in userSlice

Answer (score 1):

The `extra` available in the `thunkAPI` is the "extra argument" specified to the thunk middleware on setup.

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axiosInstance from '../service';

const store = configureStore({
  ...
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      thunk: {
        extraArgument: {
          axios: axiosInstance
        },
      },
    }),
  ...
});
```

```js
dispatch(updateUser(userData));
```

```js
const updateUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/update',
  async (userData, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const axiosInstance = thunkApi.extra.axios; 
      const { data } = await axiosInstance.put("/update-endpoint", userData);

      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      thunkApi.rejectWithError(error);
    }
  }
);
```

See [getDefaultMiddleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware) for more details and information.

An alternative would be to just import `axiosInstance` directly in the `user` slice.

```js
...
import axiosInstance from '../service';

...

const updateUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/update',
  async (userData, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axiosInstance.put("/update-endpoint", userData);

      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      thunkApi.rejectWithError(error);
    }
  }
);
```

If you ***must*** pass the `axiosInstance` from the calling React component then pass it in the action payload.

```js
dispatch(updateUser({
  data: {
    userData
  },
  extra: {
    axios: axiosInstance
  }
}));
```

```js
const updateUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/update',
  async ({ data, extra }, thunkApi) => {
    const { userData } = data;
    const { axios: axiosInstance } = extra;

    try {
      const { data } = await axiosInstance.put("/update-endpoint", userData);

      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      thunkApi.rejectWithError(error);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: axiosInstance is response from my custom useAxios hook which I am using for adding token while making requests and also taking care of 403 error by regenerating token again and making same request again

Comment: @somnathnavale Well that's a rather important detail. Please edit your post to include a ***complete*** [mcve] of all the relevant code you are working with. In the meantime I've updated my answer is another possible solution with passing the axios instance in the dispatched action.